# what are salesforce knowledge article use cases?

Tags: knowledge

I am unable to understand exact what salesforce
Knowledge  used for.
i understood that it is used to create ,publish and manage articles.
can any one describe what are the exact use cases

Answer (score 4):

Here are few  use cases

> 1)Lets say you have call center app with agents working to resolve customer problems  ,there may be already documentation based on previous solved cases and that would be help to solve the problems for cases on similar lines .
>
> 2)Say that you have a sales app and your reps need to know and learn about products so these articles can be helpful and also this they can share with customers
>
> 3)You have a self service portal for your customers and hosting all your knowledge articles will help you to reduce burden of your agents

A good example is a bluejeans [site](https://support.bluejeans.com/s/) that shows how knowledge articles are leveraged for customer service

Comment: Removed ! Thanks for notifying me that link is outdated .

Comment: My pleasure.  Will remove both of these comments to keep the post clean :-)